# Call scipy.optimize inside pyomo

Tags: python, scipy, pyomo

Can I integrate `scipy.optimize.minimize` solver with `method=SLSQP` inside pyomo? Modeling in pyomo is much faster than in scipy but pyomo documentation does not seem to say explicitly if this is feasible.

Comment: Sorry the first several words were somehow cut out. I meant to ask if I could integerate scipy.optimize.minimize solver with pyomo. Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to use SLSQP when IPOPT is available?

Comment: Because I am waiting for the approval to download HSL indefinite linear solvers which are used in IPOPT so I wanted to try something in the spare time...

Comment: IPOPT with MUMPS will still be much better (imho). (and the install-scripts also support this one incl. automatic download)

Comment: @sascha Thanks. I will also check it out. It seems I also need to wait for the request approval or get it by using wget inside Thirdparty folder. I fear this might not be the latest version so I will wait...

Comment: This waiting makes little sense to me. But a hint: that getMumps script has a version at the top. Visit *http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/*, read out the current version, replace in that file and go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (Dec 2017), there is no built-in support for passing a Pyomo model to `scipy.optimize`.  That said, it would not be a very difficult task to write a reasonably general purpose object that could generate the necessary (value, Jacobian, Hessian) evaluation functions to pass to `scipy.optimize.minimize()`.

Comment: Got it. Are you suggesting I use some auto-differentiation package to get the jacobian matrix?

Comment: Yes.  Pyomo expressions are callable to evaluate them.  Jacobian and Hessian information can be obtained through symbolic differentiation.  Assuming you have `sympy`, you could use `pyomo.core.base.symbolic.differentiate` to get Jacobian & Hessian expressions (with a modest amount of code).  You will have to delve into pyomo.core to understand how Constraint holds information, and I can give you no guarantees about the performance of using `sympy` or `scipy.optimize`.  (I would expect running the Pyomo model through ipopt to be significantly faster.)

Comment: (A year later) are there examples of calling pyomo problems from python, without derivatives ? (Your way of describing problems looks really nice.) Thanks