# Custom python solver for pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am responsible for a series of exercises for nonlinear optimization.
I thought it would be cool to start with some examples of optimization problems and solve them with `pyomo` + some black box solvers.

However, as the students learn more about optimization algorithms I wanted them to also implement some simple methods and test there implementation for the same examples. I hoped there would be an "easy" way to add a custom solver to `pyomo` however I cannot find any information about this.

Basically that would allow the students to check their implementation by just changing a single line in there code and compare to a well tested solver.

I would also try to implement a **simple** wrapper myself but I do not know anything about the `pyomo` internals.

**Q: Can I add my own solvers written in python to `pyomo`? Solver could have an interface like the ones of `scipy.optimize`.**

Ty for reading,

Franz

---

Related:

- [Pyomo-Solver Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631899/pyomo-solver-communication)
- [Call scipy.optimize inside pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821346/call-scipy-optimize-inside-pyomo)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, "Yes: Pyomo is designed to be extensible and user-defined solvers are definitely supported."

The details are a bit more involved.  While Pyomo defines several "solver" class hierarchies, they are by no means required.  The core Pyomo relies on duck-typing and not inheritance when registering and working with solvers.  At the moment, the simplest solver interface needs only to implement the following methods:

```py
class GenericSolverInterface(object):
    def solve(self,
              model: _BlockData,
              tee: bool = False,
              load_solutions: bool = True,
              logfile: Optional[str] = None,
              solnfile: Optional[str] = None,
              timelimit: Optional[float] = None,
              report_timing: bool = False,
              solver_io: Optional[str] = None,
              suffixes: Optional[Sequence] = None,
              options: Optional[Dict] = None,
              keepfiles: bool = False,
              symbolic_solver_labels: bool = False):
        pass

    def available(self, exception_flag=True) -> bool:
        pass

    def license_is_valid(self) -> bool:
        pass

    def version(self) -> Tuple:
        pass

    @property
    def options(self) -> ConfigDict:
        pass

    @options.setter
    def options(self, val):
        pass
```

Solvers are "registered" with the `SolverFactory` by either decorating the class:

```py
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

@SolverFactory.register('demo', doc='DEMO Solver interface')
class DemoSolver(GenericSolverInterface):
    #...
```

or by explicitly calling the registration function

```py
SolverFactory.register('demo', doc='DEMO Solver Interface')(DemoSolver)
```

The real trick is now how to implement the `solve()` method.  Pyomo will hand `solve()` the model (or `Block`) that the user wants to solve.  `solve()` then needs to convert the Pyomo model/Block into the format required by the solver.  This step is (obviously) very solver-specific, although there are somewhat standardized approaches for some common solver interface standards (e.g., LP files, MPS files, NL files, BAR files, etc.).  There are also other "in-development" interfaces that are more performant for specific use cases (direct in-memory solver interfaces, APPSI, PyNumero).

The simplest (and not very performant) approach could be to define a helper class that maps the Pyomo data structures to a simple set of lists:

```py
from pyomo.core.base import Objective, Constraint
from pyomo.core.expr.visitor import identify_variables

class model_interface(object):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self._obj = list(model.component_data_objects(Objective, active=True))
        self._con = list(model.component_data_objects(Constraint, active=True))
        self._var = {}
        for c in self._con:
            self._var.update({id(v): v for v in identify_variables(c.body)})
        self._var = list(self._var.values())

    @property
    def x(self):
        """Return the current list of variable values"""
        return [v.value for v in self._var]

    @x.setter
    def x(self, values):
        """Set the variables to new values"""
        for v, val in zip(self._var, values):
            v.set_value(val)

    @property
    def x_lb(self):
        """Return the list of variable lower bounds (may include None)"""
        return [v.lb for v in self._var]

    @property
    def x_ub(self):
        """Return the list of variable upper bounds (may include None)"""
        return [v.ub for v in self._var]

    @property
    def obj(self):
        """Return the list of objective values (computed using the current
        variable values)"""
        return [value(o) for o in self._obj]

    @property
    def con(self):
        """Return the list of constraint 'body' values (computed using the
        current variable values)
        """
        return [value(c) for c in self._con]

    @property
    def con_lb(self):
        """Return the list of constraint lower bounds (may include None)"""
        return [c.lb for c in self._con]

    @property
    def con_ub(self):
        """Return the list of constraint upper bounds (may include None)"""
        return [c.ub for c in self._con]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have a number of ways to do this in Pyomo and lots of examples in various modules in `pyomo.contrib`. I think the easiest way for students would be to leverage a Pyomo extension module called PyNumero which was designed for writing nonlinear optimization algorithms in Python and can be found here: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/main/pyomo/contrib/pynumero

Here are a couple implementation examples using PyNumero:

SQP --> https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/pyomo/contrib/pynumero/examples/sqp.py

Interior Point --> https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/main/pyomo/contrib/interior_point

Interfacing to Scipy square solvers --> https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/pyomo/contrib/pynumero/algorithms/solvers/scipy_solvers.py